# Why are words bit-shifted for an Atmel SAM4S SPI slave?

Tags: electrical-engineering, embedded-systems

I have discovered a problem when using the SPI peripheral in slave mode on an Atmel SAM4S.  Occasionally words can become bit-shifted.  I can force this condition by enabling the peripheral some number of clocks after `NSS` goes active.  I do this by waiting for NSSR, then using a delay loop to wait a specific time before I enable the peripheral.  I have confirmed on a scope that when the peripheral is enabled `n` clocks after `NSS` goes active, the words are shifted by `n` bits.

When the peripheral gets in this state, the only way to recover is to perform a reset (i.e. set the `SWRST` in the control register).  Disabling and re-enabling is not sufficient.

This issue has also been observed on a SAM9G45 MPU.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to the design of their SPI peripheral.  In slave mode, the shift register is shifted each `SPCK` (assuming `NSS` is low and `SPIENS` is set).  There is an internal counter (not shown in the block diagram) for the shift register, and when it reaches the word size, the contents are shifted to `SPI_RDR` and from `SPI_TDR`.  Thus if you have a word size of 8, and only 7 clocks are present for the first `NSS`, on the next `NSS`, the shift register contents will not be transferred until after the first clock cycle.

When `NSS` goes high, this counter is not reset.  Similarly, setting `SPIDIS` does not reset the counter.  Only `SWRST` resets the counter.

In addition to the method described to force this condition, glitches on `SPCK` during `NSS` (such as from EMI) can also result in a bit-shift.

[image: SAM4S Slave Mode Block Diagram]